# Write different lines in R using library(officer)

Tags: r, ms-word, officer

In R, I have a data.table that I read from an excel file that has the following records:

- good morning World
- good afternoon world

Both lines are separated by a carriage return \r\n in Excel. I am using a word template that I read with the read_docx function. Using the body_replace_all_text function I want to replace the content of the templates with the 2 lines of the excel sheet, what happens to me is that I cannot make the two lines separate in the Word sheet

example <- read_docx("C:/WORKSPACE/example.docx") #read the template from MS World
'''
Requested information
«Requested_information»
'''
df <- read_excel("C:/WORKSPACE/df.xlsx",sheet='Sheet1') #read the following text separated by \r\n
'''

- good morning World
- good afternoon world
  '''

doc <- body_replace_all_text(example, old_value = "«Requested_information»",new_value = df$"Requested Information", only_at_cursor=FALSE, ignore.case = TRUE)
print(doc, target = "C:/WORKSPACE/output.docx")

I am getting the following MS Word Document:
**Requested information**

- Good Morning World - Good Afternoon World

But I need:
**Requested information**

- Good Morning World
- Good Afternoon World

So I am not able to write in 2 different sentences in the MS Word document

Comment: Hi, there. From what you provided in `body_replace_all_text()`, `old_value` and `new_value` should be a single string, not a column. Let me know if this is the issue.

Comment: exactly my issue is that using body_replace_all_text(), , old_value and new_value I am getting the new_value from a excel file separated \r\n (Alt + return in excel) but it replace the whole dataframe information without making different parapraphs

Comment: I think you misunderstood `body_replace_all_text()`. The function can only replace one string with another string in 'example'. You cannot use `df$"Requested Information"` - a column (multiple string). You need to identify a single old string and a single new string at a time.